# Blazor Web Assembly consume API which requires authorization Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, rest, authorization, visual-studio-2019, blazor

I have created a Blazor WASM project in order to consume a third party REST API requiring authorization. In the past, this method of using Header values to `TestClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization` has worked. However, in Blazor this encoding method returns an Http 403 code every time. I know the query and credentials are valid in Postman. Here is the "Index.razor"code in which I want to view the JSON return as a string to analyze:

```
@page "/"
@inject HttpClient TestClient

<h3>Presentations Scheduled</h3>

<form>
    <fieldset class="form-group">
        <div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark mr-sm-2 mb-2"
                    @onclick=@(async ()=>  await GetToday())>Today
            </button>
        </div>
    </fieldset>

    @if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(errorString) == false)
    {
        <div class="h2">@errorString</div>
    }
    else
    {
       <div class="h2">@httpResponse</div>
    }
</form>
   
@code
{
    string errorString;
    string httpResponse;

    private async Task GetToday()
    {
        var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("user:pass");                
        TestClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
        string todayDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(0).ToString("yyyyMMdd");
        string TestbaseURL = "https://webservices.XXXAPI.com/";
        UriBuilder TestURI = new UriBuilder(TestbaseURL);
        TestURI.Scheme = "https";
        TestURI.Path = "ws/run/reservations.json";
        TestURI.Query = "resource_query_id=244782";
        var Testquery = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(TestURI.Query);
        Testquery["scope"] = "extended";
        Testquery["start_dt"] = todayDate;
        Testquery["end_dt"] = todayDate;
        TestURI.Query = Testquery.ToString();
        TestbaseURL = TestURI.ToString();

        try
        {
            httpResponse = await TestClient.GetStringAsync(TestbaseURL);
            errorString = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            errorString = $"There was a problem: {ex.Message}";
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: UPDATE - I have traced this problem to a CORS issue when I make the reqeust - I am seeing "CORS Missing allow origin"  so I am looking for a way to fix this

Answer (score 0):

I have narrowed the problem down to a CORS issue with my Blazor WASM app so I am going to answer this and start a new more focused question.